# how to make boost asio async_accept to accept only one single connection?

Tags: boost, boost-asio

I'm using the exmple in http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp11_examples.html
HTTP server

How to change the example to accept only one single connection at once. That is just accept the next connection when the previous one has finished.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In `server::do_accept` simply do **not** include the last line (which is to start another async_accept).

```
void server::do_accept()
{
  acceptor_.async_accept(socket_,
      [this](boost::system::error_code ec)
      {
        // Check whether the server was stopped by a signal before this
        // completion handler had a chance to run.
        if (!acceptor_.is_open())
        {
          return;
        }

        if (!ec)
        {
          connection_manager_.start(std::make_shared<connection>(
              std::move(socket_), connection_manager_, request_handler_));
        }

        // do_accept(); // REMOVE THIS LINE
      });
}
```

As you can see this *already* used to stop accepting connections on close.

Comment: I ll try. But...where to start it again? After the last accepted socket finishes, I would like to accept again another one.

Answer (score 0):

I did with:

```
            if (0 == connection_manager_.size()) {
            connection_manager_.start(std::make_shared<connection>(
                            std::move(socket_), connection_manager_, request_handler_));
            } else {
                std::move(socket_).close();
            }
```

Comment: This strictly doesn't answer the question, because the connections still get accepted.